# Conditional allow_nil part of validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

Writing a floating attribute validation, I stumbled upon a case where I always want to validate numericality, but only allow_nil in certain cases.

Right now my solution is to generally allow_nil, but then write a separate presence validation.

```
validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }, allow_nil: true
validates :price, presence: true,
  if: Proc.new { |v| v.voting.fan_priced? }
```

This works, but doesn't seem clean. Ideally, I would like something like this (kind of pseudo code):

```
validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0 },
  allow_nil: Proc.new { |v| v.voting.fan_priced? ? false : true }
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this more efficiently? I also found [this here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922154/rails-model-validation-conditional-allow-nil), but this seems rather similar, using two separate validations for the same thing, essentially.

**PS:** Somehow, the proc in my validation is messing up my shoulda matchers. Simple stuff like

```
it { should_not allow_value(0).for(:user_id) }
```

in the same model now gives me

```
undefined method `fan_priced?' for nil:NilClass
```

Can't the shoulda matchers handle associations in procs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way that works better using the new absence validator:

```
validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }, if: 'voting.fan_priced?'
validates :price, absence: true, unless: 'voting.fan_priced?'
```

This way, I still have two price validations, but it is more obvious through the opposing if and unless statements that they address the same context.

If anyone wants to use the absence validator, it is only available in rails 4. However, if you need it in a rails 3 project, you can simply create lib/validators/absence_validator.rb and add [this code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/absence.rb) from the rails repo. Then, create config/initializers/core_extensions.rb with the following code to make this custom validator available in each model (otherwise you may run into problems with your specs)

```
# Make custom validators available in each model
module ActiveModel::Validations
  Dir[Rails.root.join("lib/validators/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
end
```

Maybe it helps someone!

**PS:** Oh and I fixed that weird shoulda matchers error by doing

```
if: Proc.new { |v| v.voting.present? and v.voting.fan_priced? }
```

in that order.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a custom validator:

```
validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }, allow_nil: true
validate :price_presence

def price_presence
  errors.add(:price,'Price cannot be blank.') if self.voting.fan_priced? and self.price.blank?
end
```